# Run backslash/escape character from file opened

Tags: python, colors

I want to read a file and run the backslash "command" `\x1b[92m` that is stored inside the file.

I got a file that looks like this:

```
\x1b[92m this text is cyan
```

Python:

```py
f = open(f"./banners/file", "r")
content = f.read()
f.close()

print(content)
```

The output is supposed to say "this text is cyan" in a cyan color but it just prints it like this instead `\x1b[92m this text is cyan`

Just to show that it works on my os...

If I put the colorcode like this

```py
print("\x1b[92m this is cyan")
```

It prints it in cyan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f.read() escapes the backslash character so `content = '\\x1b[92m this text is cyan\n'`, when you actually print it out. Instead, when opening the file do `f=open('t.txt', 'r', encoding='unicode_escape')` so it ignores the escape charaters